# How does this toilet lid work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, friction, drag

After further reflection after closing the lid on my toilet, I noticed it exhibited a behaviour that I can't explain. When you let the lid fall, it falls at a **constant speed** regardless of its angle. This is puzzling to me as (in my understanding) acceleration from gravity acting upon an object, even an object with rotational friction, should accelerate that object (without complex hinge designs with some sort of feedback loop)

I justify this as the formula for friction **F = μN** doesn't seem to have any dynamic variables in it (heat, speed, ect.)

So how is it that with such a simple mechanism constant velocity can be achieved?

[image]

Comment: You seem to be thinking of a simple hinge rather than the possibility of a cam.

Comment: They use a hydraulic damper, where fluid is forced through a small gap as the seat falls. Unlike friction, the force is (approximately) proportional to the velocity.